# Does explicit usage of strtok is enough to make it reentrant?

Tags: c, thread-safety

Reffering to C11 (N1570 draft), 7.24.5.8 *The strtok function*:

> The `strtok` function is not required to avoid data races with other
>   calls to the `strtok` function.<sup>311)</sup>
>
> <sup>311) The `strtok_s` function can be used instead to avoid data races.</sup>

As I understand, this is due to its (global) *internal state*, which keeps information about the current position of the next token. This allows to use it like in the following idiom:

```
p = strtok(str, delim);
while (p != NULL)
{
    puts(p);
    p = strtok(NULL, delim);
}
```

Assuming that `strtok_s` (defined in Annex K) is not available, would the following usage be sufficient for reentrancy, since it ignores the internal state entirely?

```
char str[] = "ab;cd";
char * const endstr = str + strlen(str);
const char *delim = ";";

char *p = strtok(str, delim);
while (p != NULL)
{
    puts(p);

    if (p + strlen(p) == endstr) // detect ending token
        break;
    p = strtok(p + strlen(p)+1, delim);
}
```

---

#### Update:

On second thought, this technique probably should never be used, as it may lead to security issue. Since a sequence is never finished by the last call with `NULL`, the `strtok`'s internal state (consisting of an address to a token string) may be preserved during the remaining lifetime of an application.

Comment: There is no data race, it's that the function is not *reentrant*. You can not call it in different contexts (like from different threads, or even nested inside another loop already using `strtok`). If you don't use it in a threaded application, or do not nest `strtok` calls, then there is no problem.

Comment: As long as you don't call `strtok` with NULL, I think you are safe. But why use `strtok`? I think `strstr` would make it much simpler

Comment: @4386427 `strstr()` and `strtok()` work quite differently when the delimiter string is more than 1 character.  If code limits to 1 character, might as well use `strchr()`.

Comment: @chux True - but the example shows a single character

Comment: @chux - and yes - `strchr` would be fine as well. Much better than `strtok`IMO

Comment: strtok() is crippled by design. Trying to control or regulate its behaviour is useless. IMnsvHO

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> would the following usage be sufficient for reentrancy, since it ignores the internal state entirely? [...]

How do you know whether your alternative ignores `strtok()`'s internal state entirely?  The specifics of that state's nature and use are unspecified.  Therefore, without reference to a particular implementation, we know only that it is sufficient to track the start of the next token in the event that the function is called again with `NULL` as its first argument.  Nothing says it cannot be relied upon for more than that.

Now, I acknowledge that it seems *likely* that the static state should consist solely of a single `char *`, and that the function's behavior when passed a non-null first argument should not depend on the value of that static state.  I guess that's what you're describing as "reentrant".  I would not use that term for it, however, because although your approach may produce results that are unaffected by the actions of other threads, it still can affect (and engage in a data race with) other threads that do not follow the same pattern.

Finally, yes, there really is a potential for a data race involving `strtok()`.  If two different threads call `strtok()` and at least one passes `NULL` as the first argument, then both threads modify that function's static state, and at least one reads it.  `strtok()` is not required to protect its internal state in any particular way, so if the calls are not externally synchronized in some manner then there likely is a data race.  In that event program behavior is undefined.

Thus, if you have reason to be concerned about the non-reentrancy and data race risks associated with `strtok()`, and you do not want to rely on `strtok_s()` or POSIX's `strtok_r()`, then I would suggest avoiding `strtok()` altogether.  You can build a solution based on `strcspn()` instead, and such an alternative would likely be more efficient than your approach, too, because it would not need any of the `strlen()` calls.

Comment: That's right. It is rather unlikely to happen, but in theory nothing stops `strtok` to work with its internal state during the finding process. For instance, it may store the address first, and refer to it when it's about to return, which may result in some sort of data corruption, assuming that its internal state has been changed by another instance of `strtok`, that is executed in a different thread.

Comment: Agree all  points, especially the `strcspn()` which does what is required by OP's "non-reentrant" `strtok()` usage.  So much so, I see `strcspn()` a good candidate replacement for `strtok()` - just need to add the offset.

Answer (score 0):

> Does explicit usage of strtok is enough to make it reentrant?

If "explicit" is meaning "only call strtok with a non-null pointer", the answer is yes. But I wouldn't call it reentrant, though. Calling `strtok` with a non-null pointer simply means that you restart the process of splitting a string.

It is stated in the standard (draft (N1539) in 7.24.5.8 (2)

> The ﬁrst call in the sequence has a non-null ﬁrst argument;

But if you want to bypass the basic functionality of `strtok` why use it at all? You could use `strstr` or `strchr` instead. Or - as suggested by @chux in a comment - `strcspn`

Comment: I think `strcspn()` would be even a better substitute for `strtok()`.

Comment: @chux Added your suggestion

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit late, but it is re-entrant. Conventionally, `strtok` has an internal `static` variable that it uses to keep of the position within the string. If the first parameter of `strtok` is `NULL`, it refers to this internal variable in order to scan for the next token. Thus, if you yourself always provide the first parameter, it will work as you are allowed to use `strtok` for as many separate strings as you want (in this case it just so happens that the string we're passing it are all substrings of a larger string). `strtok` will simply assume you passed it a new string and work as expected.

Just keep in mind that you need to pass a non-`NULL` paramater  for every call to `strtok` for your method to work. Alternatively, I would define the following function.

```
char *my_strtok(char *str, const char *delim, char **saveptr) {
  if (*saveptr == NULL)
    return NULL;
  char *last = (str) ? str + strlen(str) : *saveptr + 1 + strlen(*saveptr + 1);
  char *ret = (str) ? strtok(str, delim) : strtok(*saveptr + 1, delim);
  *saveptr = (ret) ? ret + strlen(ret) : ret;
  *saveptr = (*saveptr != last) ? *saveptr : NULL;

  return ret;
}
```

Then your code would look like this:

```
char *str = "ab;cd";
const char *delim = ";";
char *state = str;

char *p = my_strtok(str, delim, &state);
while (p != NULL)
{
    puts(p);
    p = strtok(NULL, delim, &state);
}
```

The advantage of `my_strtok` is that it also works with nested calls.